# Palindrome check for items in a list. Return True or False for each

Tags: python

Is there a way to have a function take in a list and then return true or false for each item in the list if they are palindromes? Below is what I have tried but I would like the console to look like this:

True
False
True

```
x=[121,13,155551]

def palindrome_check(x):
    for num_from__list in x:
        if str(num_from__list) == str(num_from__list[::-1]):
            return True
            continue
        else:
            return False

print(palindrome_check(x))
```

Comment: You are returning (true or false) in the first loop cycle, so it never goes to the second and third. You're basically checking if `x[0]` is a palindrome. You should make an empty list before, and append true/false to it. Then do what you wish with the `[true, false, true]` list.

Comment: The loop in your function is meaningless because it always returns in the first iteration. Either collect the results to a list and return the list, or print in the loop inside the funciton

Comment: Also `[::-1]` should be outside `str()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `return` by `yield` hence transforming your function into a generator.

```py
def palindrome_check(x):
    for num_from__list in x:
        if str(num_from__list) == str(num_from__list[::-1]):
            yield True
        else:
            yield False

print(list(palindrome_check(x)))
```

Comment: This won't work, but I like how you found an answer with the least changes necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```py
x = [121,13,155551]

def palindrome_check(x):
    res = []
    for num_from__list in x:
        res.append(str(num_from__list) == str(num_from__list)[::-1])
    return res

print(palindrome_check(x))
```

or even better:

```py
x = [121,13,155551]

def palindrome_check(x):
    return [str(num_from__list) == str(num_from__list[::-1]) for num_from__list in x]

print(palindrome_check(x))
```

Comment: The "better" one won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `palindrome_check` function to take in a single number instead of an array of numbers and then use a list comprehension to get the results into a new list:

```
def palindrome_check(num):
    return str(num) == str(num)[::-1]

numbers = [121, 13, 155551]

results = [palindrome_check(num) for num in numbers]
print(results)
```

Right now your function returns `True` or `False` based on only the first number in the list it received, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the following:

```py
def palindrome_check(x):
  return " ".join([str(str(n) == str(n)[::-1]) for n in x])
```

Explanation:

1. For loop

   ```py
   myList = [function(n) for n in x]
   # same as
   myList = list()
   for n in x:
       myList.append(function(n))
   # eg. [n for n in x] === [121, 13, 155551]
   ```
2. Convert number to string and its mirror

   ```py
   # number
   n # eg. 123
   # string
   str(n) # eg. '123'
   # mirrored string
   str(n)[::-1] # eg. '321'
   # eg. [str(n) for n in x] === ['121', '13', '155551']
   #     [str(n)[::-1] for n in x] === ['121', '31', '155551']
   ```
3. Compare string value with its mirror

   ```py
   str(n) == str(n)[::-1] # True/False
   # eg. [str(n) == str(n)[::-1] for n in x] === [True, False, True]
   ```
4. Stringify boolean for concatenation (join)

   ```py
   str(str(n) == str(n)[::-1]) # 'True'/'False'
   # eg. [str(str(n) == str(n)[::-1]) for n in x] === ['True', 'False', 'True']
   ```
5. Concatenate string elements of a list

   ```py
   # eg. "xx".join(["A", "B", "C"]) returns 'AxxBxxC'
   " ".join([str(str(n) == str(n)[::-1]) for n in x]) # 'True False True'
   ```